# Remove leading whitespace from xml using php

Tags: php, xml

I need to remove leading white space in below xml,

```
1
2 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
3 <VAST version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vast.xsd">
4 </VAST>
```

I get above xml in variable like $html and using trim() function to remove leading white space in xml ex : echo trim($html),but it does not remove space.
Anyhelp appreciated

Comment: It might not be "just" whitespace. Try to find out which bytes are there exactly. `ord()` might help.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the leading whitespace? XML is meant for machine reading.

Comment: If I run the php files means it shows only white screen , If press ctrl+U means then only the xml visible in screen with empty space in first line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trim` only removes specific whitespace characters from a string. However if your string contains other non-rendered characters it will not work.

A candidate for this is the BOM (Byte Order Mark). It is interpreted but not rendered by the browser. So it will not be visible. The bytes itself are not part of the characters that `trim()` or `ltrim()` would remove.

Here is an example:

```
$string = "\xEF\xBB\xBF\r\n<foo/>";
var_dump(trim($string));
```

Output:

```
string(11) "﻿
<foo/>"
```

If you know that the string is XML you can use string function to remove anything before the first `<`.

```
$string = substr($string, strpos($string, '<'));
var_dump($string);
```

Output:

```
string(6) "<foo/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I seems you want to remove first line which is empty instead of white space.

To remove empty lines in php:

```
$html = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $html);
```

Comment: I tried with your answer but not getting am expected result, Always shows empty space in first line

Answer (score 0):

If you get the whitespace at the beginning each time you could use  `ltrim($html)`

Comment: yes tried, getting same result always shows empty space in first line

Comment: `$html='
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VAST version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vast.xsd">

</VAST>';


echo "<pre>";
print_r( simplexml_load_string(ltrim($html)));`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem in a WP theme and I fixed it by doing the following:

1. Create an .html file - eg. rsshead.html with the content: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` - starting at the very beginning of the file at line 1; encoding can be changed to whatever suits you best
2. Include the HTML file into my PHP file: `include('rsshead.html');` instead of `echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It appeared that one of the files included before the XML-generating code contained a space just before the `<?php` declaration:

```
 <?php
```

instead of

```
<?php
```